# Pass AJAX response within Angular Controller to bind HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I need to bind some HTML code to the response of a AJAX request. Since the AJAX is asynchronous, I need to place the code that does the actual binding within my AJAX callback function, like so:

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  angular.module('poetry', [])
  .controller('poetryController', poetryController);

  poetryController.$inject = ['$scope', '$sce']

  function poetryController ($scope, $sce) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: myURL,
      data: {'per_page': 100},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: callback
    });
    function callback(response) {
      var list = new Array
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var string = '<li><h3>' + response[i]['title']['rendered'] + '</h3></li>';
        list.push(string)
      }
      $scope.html_code = list.join("")
      $scope.bindHTML = function(html_code) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code)
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

What ends up happening is that the HTML doesn't get sent to the page, and I'm left with empty content. I'm quite confident the problem is in this line here

```
$scope.bindHTML = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code)
}
```

and something to do with the scope of the `$scope.bindHTML` variable.
What should I do to make `$scope.html_code` pass to the `$scope.bindHTML` function?

Also, no errors show in the console.

My HTML:

```
<body ng-app="poetry">
  <div href="#" class="container" ng-controller="poetryController">
    <ul class="grid effect-6" id="grid" ng-bind-html="bindHTML(html_code)"></ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you don't need a function declaration inside a callback. Also use `$http.get()` instead of `$.ajax()`

Comment: Thank you. I googled and used `$http.get()` and now everything works. I no longer have to use bindHTML. There's now a slight problem which is kinda off topic, but maybe you can help me with it. The JSON object I'm retrieving has index values as its keys. In order to access the values within the keys, I've written the HTML as such: `<li ng-repeat="x in myData">{{x.$index.title.rendered}}</li>`. `$index` returns the proper index of the list, but I can't seem to use it as key values. I googled this too but couldn't find anything. What's the proper syntax to use in this situation? Thanks again.

Comment: I think you need 2 `ng-repeat`, one for array, and one (inner) for object. It will pull the keys and values separately with this syntax: `ng-repeat="(key, value) in x"`. Or you could try replacing dot syntax with square brackets: `x[$index].title.rendered`

Comment: You mean one `li` tag with the first `ng-repeat="x in myData"` and then another tag within the `li`with another `ng-repeat="(key, value) in x"`?

Comment: I'm not sure what format you are looking for (bullet points with bullet points?)

Comment: No, but everything is good now :)) I used `(key, val) in myData`. With val, I referenced the individual keys within the values like `val.title.rendered`.